# Find Additions or deletions in a TRANSFORM (.MST)

Tags: windows-installer

I am reading a MST file using VBScript, I have managed others but how do I get the following:

Find which entries in a specific table were only added.
Find which entries in a specific table were only modified.
Find which entries in a specific table were only deleted.

The available methods in MSDN tells the changes made, but not by the category - addition/modifications/deletion, or at least I didn't find any.

Comment: I'm not sure who voted this question down but I think it's a wonderful question.  I know how to programmatically generate transforms and I know if you apply them in ORCA that ORCA will show you in green which tables and rows have been modified but it's never occurred to me to figure out what API calls ORCA makes to determine this.  I just did a quick review of the MSI and DTF SDKs and nothing jumped out at me.  I'll keep reading but I'm guessing Rob will have a great answer.  He did write ORCA after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at WiLstXfm.vbs found in the SDK.  It shows how to use the _TransformView table to figure out what the changes were.

If you create a dummy MST with one add, one remove and one change you'll see it reports back:

one delete
one change
one insert / change   ( from null to new value )

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Dear Christopher. Sorry if I was late to reply, but I am not so good at scripting, so been spending the last few days decoding and trying to implement what you graciously showed me the way, with my requirement. I am just lucky, I cracked it without anymore bothering qns. :( Is it fine, if I provide a portion of the script on I achieved it (in layman terms possibly) for future use by anyone, if it be helpful.